# Value of a column at time t is subracted by running mean of the past 1000 values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe called `df`.

It has a column name `x`.

I want to update the `df['x']` such that value at index i is changed to value at index i - mean of previous 1000 values.

How to achieve that in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`rolling.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html) and [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and subtract the value in place:

```
df['x'] -= df['x'].rolling(1000, min_periods=1).mean().shift()
```

Example of the logic with a rolling on the 3 previous values:

```
   x  rolling_mean     shift  x-prev_3
0  5      5.000000       NaN       NaN
1  0      2.500000  5.000000 -5.000000
2  3      2.666667  2.500000  0.500000
3  3      2.000000  2.666667  0.333333
4  7      4.333333  2.000000  5.000000 # = 7 - (3+3+0)/3
5  9      6.333333  4.333333  4.666667
6  3      6.333333  6.333333 -3.333333
7  5      5.666667  6.333333 -1.333333
8  2      3.333333  5.666667 -3.666667
9  4      3.666667  3.333333  0.666667
```

Comment: Can you explain what min_periods = 1 does?

Comment: This is to compute the mean of the initial 999 rows where there is less than 1000 previous values. Without it, you'll get NaN. Remove it if you prefer to have NaNs. I encourage you to read the documentation linked in my answer.